# If $I$ is a homogeneous ideal of $A$ contained in $A_+$, then $\sqrt{I} = \bigcap\limits_{I\subset P\in\text{Proj }A} P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

**EDIT:**

This is from an exercise of Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*.

> 4.5.H: Suppose $I$ is any homogeneous ideal of $S$ contained in $S_+$, and if $f$ is a homogeneous element of positive degree, show that $f$ vanishes on $V(I)$, i.e. $V(I)\subset V(f)$ iff $f^n\in I$ for some $n$.

The definition of $V(I)$ is the set of all homogeneous prime ideals containing $I$ but not $S_+$.

**My thoughts:**

Now one direct is clear. I want to show the reverse. I think it translates to the following:
$$\sqrt{I} = \bigcap_{I\subset P\in\text{Spec }A} P = \bigcap_{I\subset P\in\text{Proj }A} P.$$
But this seems to be false? How should I go about then?

Comment: There are homogeneous $A_+$-primary ideals.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Edited again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Reduce the problem modulo $I$ and then consider the localization $S_f$. [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385292/homogeneous-ideals-are-contained-in-homogeneous-prime-ideals) that any graded ring has a graded prime ideal.

Comment: So the statement regarding the radical is correct?

Comment: @mez Localizing at $f$ throw away the irrelevant maximal ideal $S_+$, this is why the hint works. For the radical you also want to lose it, but I'm afraid this is not possible: if $I=(X^2,Y)$ in $S=K[X,Y]$, then its radical is exactly $S_+$. (There is no other homogeneous prime containing $I$ excepting $S_+$.) But the radical of $I$ is the intersection of *all* homogeneous primes containing $I$.

Comment: I see, so the equality should be $\sqrt{I} = A_+\cap \bigcap\limits_{I\subset P\in \text{Proj } A} P = \bigcap\limits_{I\subset P} P$ where all ideals considered are homogeneous.

Comment: @mez Right!${}$