# $\Bbb Z$-graded ring with no nonzero homogeneous prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Exercise $2.18$ in Eisenbud's algebra book asks to prove:

Suppose $R=\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^\infty R_n$ is a $\Bbb Z$-graded ring such that any homogeneous prime ideal is zero. Prove $R_0$ is a field.

To do the first part I have tried to show that any maximal ideal $M$ of $R_0$  is zero, by somehow using $M$ to build a prime homogeneous ideal of $R$ containing $M$, but I can't see how.

Comment: Can use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385292/homogeneous-ideals-are-contained-in-homogeneous-prime-ideals

Comment: @user26857, yes, that works, thanks!